# CSS3 calc function works only in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, compatibility

So I have been doing something with calc function in CSS3 and apparently even tho internet says it's compatible with almost every browser, for me it still works only in Google Chrome(right now I am trying to get it working in Mozilla Firefox). This is how that line looks like:

```
   td{
       border:1px solid black;
       width: -moz-calc(100% / 5);
   }
```

Comment: have you got any html to go with this

Comment: -moz-calc is only supported by Mozilla according to this: http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/-moz-calc(). Are you sure you didn't mean `calc(100% / 5)`?

Comment: See [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for a browser support chart for `calc()`, including prefix requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me in firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/rYFNj/

I think your issue is with the fact you are trying to do it on a `td` as these behave differently to normal block elements and will take up the width of the row it is in

[Please note thought that Mozilla still considers this to be experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: **-moz** properties belongs to Mozilla CSS Extensions, which may or may not support with other browsers.

Comment: @NK can you see any reference to `-moz` in my answer?  And it won't be supported by any other browser unless they are running an earlier version of gecko rendering engine

Comment: Because you said 'Seems to work for me in firefox'. -moz extensions will always work with firefox.

Comment: actually no they won't the `-moz-calc` won't work with the latest version of firefox

Comment: Did u try `width: calc(100px - 8);`. I mean just calc(). Usage of -moz-calc is found like that. [-moz-calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcalc)

Comment: Yes I tried without a prefix and it's the same thing, I guess I'll just put divs instead of table, seemed much faster when I was doing it, now I regret it...